# undefined index error occurs even the code works fine

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to do form validation and storing the validated data in mysql database using php.The code works fine as its supposed to do save the form data in mysql db after the validation process.The problem is it shows the undefined index error in these lines
1.`<span class="error">* <?php echo $error['name'];?></span>`
2.`<span class="error">* <?php echo $error['email']; ?></span>`
3.`<span class="error"><?php echo $error['website']; ?></span>`
4.`<span class="error">* <?php echo $error['gender'];?></span>`.

here is my full code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
 <head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$error=array();
$name = $email = $gender = $comment = $website = $data = "";
function test_input($data)
{

 $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
 return $data;
}
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
if (empty($_POST["name"]))
 {$error['name']= "Name is required";}
else
 {
 $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
 // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
 if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name))
   {
   $error['name'] = "Only letters and white space allowed";
   }
 }

 if (empty($_POST["email"]))
 {$error['email'] = "Email is required";}
 else
 {
 $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
 // check if e-mail address syntax is valid
 if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email))
   {
   $error['email'] = "Invalid email format";
   }
 }

 if (empty($_POST["website"]))
 {$website = "";}
 else
 {
 $website = test_input($_POST["website"]);
 // check if URL address syntax is valid 
 (this regular expression also allows dashes   in the URL)
 if (!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)
 [-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$website))
   {
   $error['website'] = "Invalid URL";
   }
 }

if (empty($_POST["comment"]))
 {$comment = "";}
else
 {$comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);}

if (empty($_POST["gender"]))
 {$error['gender'] = "Gender is required";}
else
 {$gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]);}
}

?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
<span class="error">* <?php echo $error['name'];?></span>
<br><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
<span class="error">* <?php echo $error['email']; ?></span>
<br><br>
Website: <input type="text" name="website" value="<?php echo $website;?>">
<span class="error"><?php echo $error['website']; ?></span>
<br><br>
Comment: <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"><?php echo $comment;?></textarea>
<br><br>
Gender:
<input type="radio" name="gender" 
<?php if (isset($gender) &&  $gender=="female") 
echo "checked";?>    value="female">Female
<input type="radio" name="gender" 
<?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="male") echo   "checked";?>  value="male">Male
<span class="error">* <?php echo $error['gender'];?></span>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }

$sql="INSERT INTO np_appoint (Name,Email,Website,Comment,Gender)
VALUES


('$_POST[Name]','$_POST[Email]','$_POST[website]','$_POST[Comments]','$_POST[Gender]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
 {
 die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid undefined values use `isset().`

```
<span class="error"> <?php if(isset($error['name']))
echo $error['name'];?></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because if there is no error the `$error` array is not defined.

try defining the wariables at the beginning of your code>

```
$error['name'] = '';
$error['email'] = '';
$error['website'] = '';
$error['gender'] = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error messages are set one at a time, but the keys in `$error` array are not predefined. So if name is valid you will not have `$error['name']`. This will produce a undefined index NOTICE.

Answer (score 0):

Attempting to access an array key which has not been defined is the same as accessing any other undefined variable gives an E_NOTICE-level error message like `undefined index`

Try this, `count($error)>0`

```
 <?php if(count($error)>0){?>
   <span class="error">* <?php echo $error['name'];?></span>
<?php } ?>
```

OR

You can use `foreach`

```
<?php foreach($error as $value){?>
   <span class="error">* <?php echo $value;?></span>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

USe isset() function

```
<span class="error">* <?php if(isset($error['name']))
echo $error['name'];?></span>
```

Or error supressing using `@` (not recommended )

```
<span class="error">* <?php   echo @$error['name'];?></span>
```